# Accuracy loss when calculating magnitudes <1 with magnitudes >1

Tags: c++, string, boost, gmp, arbitrary-precision

I'm testing string constructed [`gmp_float`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/gmp_float.html).

This code

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/number.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/gmp.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;

typedef number<gmp_float<15>> mp_type;

int main()
{
    mp_type total("1.01");
    cout << total.str(0) << endl;
    mp_type first_addition(".01");
    cout << first_addition.str(0) << endl;
    total += first_addition;
    cout << total.str(0) << endl;
}
```

prints

```
1.01
0.01
1.01999999999999999998
```

Why?  I ran more tests, and in this particular case, it doesn't matter what the operation is so long as the magnitude of one number is >0 and <1 while the other's is >1.

From the link above

> It is not possible to round-trip objects of this type to and from a string and get back exactly the same value. This appears to be a limitation of GMP.

Are there any other zones where accuracy is lost?

Comment: Even if `gmp_float` is advertised as having a "much greater precision", I doubt the precision is infinite. Especially around `0`.

Comment: [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a66922dce0a3eb9f) I've reproduced the issue, for those interested.

Comment: Floating-point is subject to accuracy issues the farther you get from [0.0,1.0]. If you want the same accuracy within the entire range of values representable, use fixed-point instead. You cannot even represent **0.01** as a power-of-two in floating-point, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost Multiprecision has decimal floating point numbers too:

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/317c437d6d239584)** prints:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -Os -Wall -pedantic main.cpp && ./a.out
1.01
0.01
1.02
```

---

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_dec_float.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::multiprecision;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

typedef cpp_dec_float_50 mp_type;

int main()
{
    mp_type total("1.01");
    cout << total.str(0)          << endl;

    mp_type first_addition(".01");
    cout << first_addition.str(0) << endl;

    total += first_addition;
    cout << total.str(0)          << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`mpf_t` in GMP is a **binary** floating-point number.  `0.01` is not exactly representable as a binary floating point number of any finite precision.

Changing `0.01` for `0.125` and `1.01` for `1.125` makes the formatted output look fine.  This is because `0.125` and `1.125` are exactly representable as binary floating-point numbers with at least 8 bits of significand.

Comment: I believe `gmp_float` just wraps `mpf_t`.  The `mpf_class` I've used does just wrap `mpf_t`.

Comment: @Gracchus: Why?  Why do you care about powers of ten?

Comment: @Gracchus: Gross.  Measure everything in cents or whatever the smallest unit of currency being measured is.  Or use some decimal floating-point bunk if you really have to.  Binary floating-point will still be your friend should you choose to understand it.

Comment: @Gracchus: Decimal floating-point formats and libraries exist.  I do not think gmp has one.  I have no experience with them, so I can't recommend which to use.

Comment: +1 for informative, I've answered with a proper boost solution